# how to make HTML from a list in scheme, racket

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket, mutual-recursion

This is a very long question ... I am new and joined, so please don't attack me. Apologies for my bad communications in English. I have some defintions:

An HTML(H) is one of

- `Str`
- `Tag`

A Tag is

- `(cons Sym (listof H))`

I want to use mutual recursion,make the HTML into real HTML code. For example,

```
(list 'html (list 'head (list 'title "Hi")) (list 'body (list 'h1 "Welcome") "Text"))
```

Turns into:

```
"<html><head><title>Hi</title></head><body><h1>Welcome</h1>Text</body></html>"
```

This should work for any list or string. There are rules for turning it into HTML:

- A string does not need to turn into HTML.
- Each Tag (this is from the definitions) begin with `<tag>` and end with `</tag>`.  So `<html>` and `</html>`.

If they enter a string, "Hello", then it does not convert anything. I wrote code here, but it does not work ...

```
(define (html->string html)
  (cond [(string? html) html]
    [else (append (list "<" (first html) ">") (change-tag (rest html)) (list "</" (first html) ">"))]))


(define (change-tag lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) empty]
    [else (append (html->string (list (first lst)))
                  (html->string (list (rest lst))))]))
```

If I enter something like:

```
(list 'html (list 'head (list 'title "Hi")) (list 'body (list 'h1 "Welcome") "Text"))
```

Then it gives me:

```
(list "<" 'html ">" "<" (list 'head (list 'title "Hi")) ">" "</" (list 'head (list 'title "Hi")) ">" "<" (list  (list 'body  (list 'h1 "Welcome").....etc etc
```

It is a very long output and it does not work. How to be able to fix this?

Comment: Are you using `append` where you meant to use `string-append`, between strings?

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea, but still - there are three main issues with your proposed solution:

- The output will be a *string*, not a *list*, so we must append strings in the recursive steps and return strings in the base cases.
- Symbols must be explicitly converted to strings if we want to concatenate them with other strings.
- And last but not least: you're missing a couple of base cases, and these are essential for writing a correct solution: what should happen if the given html is an empty list? What if the first element in a list is not a symbol, but another list?

This will work, take a careful look at the things that changed:

```
(define (html->string html)
  (cond [(empty? html) ""]
        [(string? html) html]
        [(not (symbol? (first html)))
         (html->string (first html))]
        [else (string-append
               "<" (symbol->string (first html)) ">"
               (change-tag (rest html))
               "</" (symbol->string (first html)) ">")]))

(define (change-tag lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) ""]
        [else (string-append
               (html->string (first lst))
               (html->string (rest lst)))]))
```

It works as expected:

```
(define html
  (list 'html
        (list 'head
              (list 'title "Hi"))
        (list 'body
              (list 'h1 "Welcome")
              "Text")))

(html->string html)
=> "<html><head><title>Hi</title></head><body><h1>Welcome</h1>Text</body></html>"
```